# Php Date function not working in live server

Tags: php, date

i am  displaying the current date & time  using php in localhost using below date function

```
<?php
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

and  displaying output as `2013-06-24 14:45:13`
But when i run the above php code in the live server it is displaying output as `2013-06-24 06:47:28`.
So, any one tell how could display the date and time in 24 hour format in the live server..

Comment: It probably is a timezone issue. Use `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T');` to see what each server has its timezone set to.

Comment: add date_default_timezone_set('your timezone') at the first line, [list of valide timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: If it works in testing, but not production, then it's probably either a) your timezone is set incorrectly. Check the php.ini that you have date.timezone set or b) your server is set at the wrong time.

Answer (score 5):

This is a timezone issue.Check

```
date_default_timezone_get();
```

Using `date_default_timezone_set('YOUR_TIMEZONE');` you can set timezone.

Answer (score 2):

Your server seems not to have the same timezone as your localhost.

Or maybe the time is simply not well set.

Answer (score 2):

Seems a timezone issue or settings not properly set on server as theoretically it should display time and date as of server

Regarding Timezone issue, see this guide for `date_default_timezone_set`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 1):

The date function takes the current date and time. Now it will display only the date and time will be displayed that is at server.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('now'); 
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

?>
```

Also, the date/time displayed is server's one, so you should also set the timezone:

```
<?php

$timezone = DateTimezone('{Continent}/{City}');
$date = new DateTime('now', $timezone); 
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are running this code `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` in localhost it is taking your system time but when you run this `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` on live server it uses the SERVER Timezone. Use this function `date_default_timezone_get()`. It returns the default timezone used by all date/time functions in the script and you can use it to set the time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Use `date_default_timezone_set` to sent corrent time zone from your script.

You can find more info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

or

```
date_default_timezone_set('Egypt/Cairo');
```

or what ever between ('')